# Signalr Connect Disconnect and reconnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am wanting to make sure that I am implementing the group feature correctly for the SignalR library.

What I am doing is allowing users to ask for help for a specific project. The user that started the project can add other users to a collaboration table for their project.

```
Collaboration 
(
    UserID Uniqueidentifier,
    ProjectID INT
)
```

If either user goes into collaboration mode I want to add that user to a group so if another user logs on and goes into collaboration mode they are added to the same group. The groups are always named the `ProjectID`.

So when a user logs on and opens a projects if that project is in the collaboration table I add them to the `Groups.Add(Conext.ConnectionId,projID)`;

---

Here are my questions:

When a user connects from the client and the OnConnected is called if no group with the projID exists will this throw an error or will signalr just create that group on the fly?

```
    public override Task OnConnected(string projID)
    {
        return Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, projID);
    }
```

When a client closes their browser, is that when the OnDisconnected is called?
And if that user for some reason is not in the said projID group will this throw and error or will signalr handle this?

```
    public override Task OnConnected(string projID)
    {
        return Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, projID);
    }
```

For the OnReconnected, does this mean that if a user logs off and does something else then logs back on that they are automatically added back to the group they where part of before the connect was lost?

```
    public override Task OnReconnected(string projID)
    {
        return Clients.Group(projID).rejoined(Context.ConnectionId,
            DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
```

For all of the methods above do I need to call the base method of each overrided method?

Comment: No offence mate but why don't you just try it? 1. Created if not exists. 2. Yes disconnected is called when the session is ended (browser close event); It wont throw an error and will be handled if that user is not in that group. 3. Reconnected is if the client hasnt sent a heartbeat in a while and suddenly reconnects due to lost network connections etc. That code you posted handles the re-adding of the user to that group with its new connection id after reconnect.

Comment: Why didn't you just answer with that comment and I could of marked your comments as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. SignalR will create the group when you call `Groups.Add()` for the
   first time for a particular `projID`. It won't throw an error.
2. `OnDisconnected` is called whenever the connection goes away. If you
   call `Stop()` there is a clean disconnect and the `OnDisconnected`
   method is called immediately. If you just shut the browser, the
   `OnDisconnected` method will usually be called after a delay of
   about 30 seconds (there's a configuration switch to control this)
3. Users are tied to specific groups based on their connection id's. If
   a user comes back with a different connection id you will have to
   add it again to the appropriate group. You can have a look at the
   Chat sample provided with SignalR to see how cases such as this can
   be handled.